# angularjs ng-if difference between value and function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any difference using
ng-if with a value or with a function ?

```
ng-if="myvalue"
ng-if="myfunc()"
```

UPDATE (for a better understanding why I'm asking for)

### html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" data-ng-controller="NavController as nav">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <a data-ui-sref="home" class="navbar-brand"><i class="logo"></i> Angular Express</a>
                    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a data-ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-ng-if="!nav.isAuthenticated()">
                    <li><a data-ui-sref="session.login">Log in</a></li>
                    <li><a data-ui-sref="session.signup">Sign up</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-ng-if="nav.isAuthenticated()">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span ng-bind="nav.isAuthenticated().username"></span> <a href="/api/auth/logout" data-ng-click="nav.logout()">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

### js

```
function NavController($rootScope, UserStorage){
    var nav = this;
    nav.isAuthenticated = function() {
        UserStorage.get();
    }; 
}
function UserLoginController($rootScope,$state, Users, UserStorage) {
    var user = this;
    user.data = {};
        user.save = function() {
            Users.login(user.data).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            UserStorage.set(response.data);
            $state.go('home');
        })
        .catch(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            user.errors = response.data;
        });
    };
}
```

If I use like this I've got a $digest() iterations reached

### RE UPDATE

(for chandermani comment)

```
function UserStorage($sessionStorage) {
  return {
    set: function(data) {
        $sessionStorage.user = angular.toJson(data);
    },
    get: function() {
        return angular.fromJson($sessionStorage.user); 
    },
    del: function() {
        delete $sessionStorage.user;
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For angular both are `expression`, that it evaluates in context of current scope. Angular does this on each digest cycle.

There are more ways to shoot in the foot if you are using the function way. `myfunc` could do

```
$scope.myfunc=function() {
   //do some time consuming work
   return data;
};
```

In such a case the binding evaluation on each digest cycle will make your binding and app slow.

So if you are using function based binding make sure that functions return fast by doing minimum processing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've just asking for because in my script if I use func that triggers a $digest() iterations reached but the func is very light like nav.isLogged = function() {
       UserStorage.get();
     };

Comment: Please add some code for function `UserStorage.get();`

Comment: Does your function isLogged function return value or just call UserStorage.get();

Comment: return an object (just the user data)

Comment: So in that case each time a new object is created with `return angular.fromJson($sessionStorage.user); `, which does not match original. Either stay away from function or use  nav.isAuthenticated = function() {
       return UserStorage.get()!==null;
    };

Answer (score 0):

Calling functions on ng-repeat directives can cause some performance issues, but if it's a one off evaluation then there isn't really a difference as far as I've noticed.

I always try to evaluate the property: `ng-if="myValue"` would evaluate the scope variable `$scope.myValue`