# Is it a bad practice to use function call in ng-if/*ngIf?

Tags: angularjs

Is it a bad practice to use the return value of a function call inside ng-if. Will it affect the digest cycle/performance?

Comment: Check [angularjs ng-if difference between value and function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856927/angularjs-ng-if-difference-between-value-and-function)

Comment: it would if it didn't return same value each iteration. Not common but have seen it if someone tries to return something random for example will cause infinite digest problem and thus an abort

Comment: Uhmmm... hard to know... this question has both angularjs and angular2 tags, but was the question about angular1 or angular2? No one will ever know...

Answer (score 6):

As any expression used in the view, it will be reevaluated at each digest cycle to see if its value has changed or not, and thus if the element must be removed or added to the DOM.

If the function is simple enough, no problem. If it tries to compute the 10000th decimal of pi, you'll have performance problems. What matters is to understand what you're doing, and how it works.

So if you feel using a function makes your code simpler, go for it, and start optimizing if you really need to.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's just fine. The function shouldn't have side effects (especially not change other fields taking part in change detection)

Answer (score 0):

Function calls will be slightly slower than just pure evaluation of a variable on scope due primarily to the fact that the step of "run function" must be handled before "check truthiness" is run on either. But this performance impact depends on how long your function takes to run.

Generally, anything that constitutes complex logic can be extracted out into a function and it will clean up your HTML since you won't need long JS in your template file.

I often extract to a function if the statement cannot be done in a single JS statement or if the statement starts being longer than about 40 characters.

Comment: now add a console.log into your "not so complex logic" and see how many time it gets called.