# function triggered by Html element running before service return response

Tags: angular, observers, angular-observable

I'm having a simple component that display a list of links. Each link should be displayed\hide according to permissions. In order to get the permissions set, I should use a service. 
This is a lean version of the HTML:

```
<a *ngIf=isVisible(10) routerLink=".." [queryParams]="{id:'10'}">bla1</a>     
<a *ngIf=isVisible(40) routerLink=".." [queryParams]= "{id:'20'}">bla2</a>
```

This is the component:

```
constructor(private reportService : service) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.reportService.GetReportsPermissions().subscribe(result => 
    {
      this.reportsPersmissions = result;
    }, error => { console.log(error)});
 }

 isVisible(reportTypeID : ReportType) : boolean
 {
   return typeof this.reportsPersmissions != 'undefined' && 
     this.reportsPersmissions.find(rp => rp.ReportType == 
     reportTypeID).IsPermitted;
 }
```

The problem is that isVisible function is called when the service is not yet responded and  reportsPersmissions is undefined. 
I could think of another option of add

```
*ngIf= reportsPersmissions
```

statement as a container div around the list of links:

```
<div *ngIf=reportsPersmissions> //Optional - see below
  <a *ngIf=isVisible(10) routerLink=".." [queryParams]="{id:'10'}">bla1</a>     
  <a *ngIf=isVisible(40) routerLink=".." [queryParams]= "{id:'20'}">bla2</a>        
</div>
```

Is this the right way of doing it or is there a better way (best practice) doing that ?

Comment: Are you returning typeof the variable i.e boolean or int and trying to use them in ngIf

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to calculate the `isVisible` condition on the `NgOnInit`and then put it on the `ngIf`as a variable instead of a function, which may cause performance problems (since it's being executed on the digest cycle).

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.reportService.GetReportsPermissions().subscribe(result => {
        this.reportsPersmissions = result;

        // Iterate over the reports and calculate the isVisible variable here

    }, error => { console.log(error)});
}

*ngIf="report.isVisible"
```

In your case, I don't think it may cause performance problems, but take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842835/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-function-call-in-ng-if-ngif).